# android reading bitmap from url in image listview

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, smooth-scrolling

I have a question about android bitmap loading in listview.I have 980 image url so I must show this images in a listview or recyclerview.Smooth scrolling and rapid startup are  very important .How can I load images with multithreading?.Using asysnc task or java thread pool (executor).which is more effective? when User scroll fastly , it must execute last threads and there must no thread problem.(stopping old  threads).

not: ı must not use third party libraries and components

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: if you implement a recyclerview properly, it automatically handles all this for you.  You can't keep the images in memory and it unloads the controls as it scrolls.  You should use thumbnails for speed.  It's called a recyclerview because it actually uses the exact same controls over and over as you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Glide or Picasso inside a RecyclerView.

Also read that documentation, it is very important : [Handling bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/)

Google team recommend to use Glide, they said in that link :

> For most cases, we recommend that you use the Glide library to fetch,
>   decode, and display bitmaps in your app. Glide abstracts out most of
>   the complexity in handling these and other tasks related to working
>   with bitmaps and other images on Android.

Comment: ı must not use third party components

Comment: @ahmetvefa53 updated. Google fairly recommends developers to use Glide. Since you will also need to import RecyclerView anyway...

Comment: what is the differences of recyclerview about loading images

Comment: RecyclerView will make the user think that the number of Views == number of images but in reality they are recycling the invisible (and not cached) views. Combined with Glide, it is very powerful. You can release memory inside a method called onViewRecycled, and inside you can clear view using Glide. Etc... It fits exactly what you need (including loading image from url in an efficient way)

Comment: I could not understand that "RecyclerView will make the user think that the number of Views == number of images but in reality they are recycling the invisible (and not cached) views." can you explain better?